# Azure pipeline yaml get last element of split function

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, pipeline

Likely an easy question, but I'm stuck on it for a while. In an Azure pipeline YAML file, I'm trying to split the content of a variable and take the last item of the split

In the code below for Variable3 I try to solve the easier case of taking the 2nd item of the split. However, for some reason, Variable2 works fine, while Variable3 is not working (empty result). Can someone help explain why my attempt is failing and how I should get the last element of the split in a correct way?

Thanks!

```
variables:
- name: Variable1
  value: 'abc/def/ghi'
- name: Variable2
  value: $[replace(variables['Variable1'],'/',',')]
- name: Variable3
  value: $[split(variables['Variable1'], '/')[1]]

trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

stages:
- stage: stage1
  jobs:
  - job: job1
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - script: echo '$(Variable2)'
    - script: echo '$(Variable3)'
```

Comment: Can you not use the length() function to determine the array size then subtract 1 to get the last entry, not in a position to test this but just thought I'd mention it - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the code below for Variable3 I try to solve the easier case of taking the 2nd item of the split.

To meet your requirement, you can use the following format to split the variable and get the second value: `${{split(variables['Variable1'], '/')[1]}}`

Here is an example:

```
variables:
- name: Variable1
  value: 'abc/def/ghi'
- name: Variable2
  value: $[replace(variables.Variable1,'/',',')]
- name: Variable3
  value: ${{split(variables['Variable1'], '/')[1]}}

trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

stages:
- stage: stage1
  jobs:
  - job: job1
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - script: echo '$(Variable2)'
    - script: echo '$(Variable3)'
```

Result:

[image]

To get the last element of split function, we need to manually input the position of the last element. For example: `${{split(variables['Variable1'], '/')[2]}}`.

Azure DevOps doesn't support the format: `${{split(variables['Variable1'], '/')[-1]}}` for the time being.

**Update:**

Workaround: we can split the variable in Powershell and get the last value to set the variable

```
variables:
- name: Variable1
  value: abc/def/ghi
- name: Variable2
  value: $[replace(variables['Variable1'],'/',',')]


trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

stages:
- stage: stage1
  jobs:
  - job: job1
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          $b = "$(Variable1)".Split("/")
          $lastvalue= $b[-1]
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Variable3]$lastvalue"
    - script: echo '$(Variable2)'
    - script: echo '$(Variable3)'
```

Comment: Thank you! I was struggling a lot with this. Why does the $[] notation process this differently than ${{}}? I don't understand that.
Furthermore, in the actual problem case, I won't know how many '/' symbols will be in Variable1, but I still need the last item (i.e. I won't know the index beforehand). Do you know how to get the last item in general?

Comment: For the difference of the $[]  and the  ${{}} , the $[] is runtime and the ${{}} is the compile time. Based on my test, the split command needs to use compile time expression. I can fully understand your requirement. But I am afraid that there is no method can directly get the last element  at the varaible define time. For a workaround, we can split the value with powershell script and use logging command to set the variable. I will wait a sample, give me few minutes.

Comment: @kerel123 Please check the update and check if it can work for you.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks for your efforts and explanation!